# In the model, is there a way to get the results of a controller request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a model Feed. is there a way to get the results of a controller call.

```
   class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
      output = ControllerName.Action(params)
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't (well if you really want to you can, but you shouldnt). Your controller should call a method from your model instead. Another alternative is to create a module and use it as a mixin in both classes.